# pear DB: very strange behaviour

Tags: php

Consider the following code

```
    $dsn = array('phptype'  => 'mysql',
        'username' => Config::DB_STORE_USERNAME,
        'password' => Config::DB_STORE_PASSWORD,
        'hostspec' => Config::DB_STORE_HOSTNAME,
        'database' => Config::DB_STORE_NAME);
    echo '222222';
    $db = DB::connect($dsn);
    echo '111111';
    if (PEAR::isError($db)) {
        echo '2143234234235';
        return null;
    }
```

`222222` is outputed while `111111`. Still no error is outputed (in `php.ini` `error_reporting` is `E_ALL`). Have you any idea how is it possible to track the issue?

**UPD:** if it helps, I installed DB not with `pear install DB` but simply downloaded and unpacked archive.

Comment: Please enabled `display_errors`, set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` or `-1`, and if my crystal ball works, it will show you an error about `DB` not being a recognized class (did you include your `PEAR` library /  set the `include_path`?

Comment: @Wrikken,I didn't install `DB` with `pear`. It's included correctly (if I change include path Fatal Error is thrown)

Comment: unpacked the archive where? dropping it into some random folder is not going to help PHP find it.

Comment: @MarcB,I included that folder with `ini_set`

Comment: @Eugeny89: so, pray tell _what_ fatal error does it throw? Because you _did_ enable `display_errors` like I asked, did you?

Comment: if I enter wrong path, there shown respective error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the examples suggests, does

```
if (PEAR::isError($db)) {
die($db->getMessage()); }
```

outputs anything?